# How can I make required cck date field "not required" by hook_form_alter?

Tags: entities, 6, datetime

I could make some requited cck fields "not required"  by hook_form_alter a below but this doesn't work for date field.

for selection type

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
$form['field_smaple_1']['#required'] = 0; 
}
```

or

for text are type

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
$form['field_sample_2']['0']['#required'] = '';
}
```

How can I do the same thing for date field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To alter date field required to disable, you can use following snippet in your form alter

```
$form['#field_info']['field_date']['required']=0; //field_date use your field name
```